# Pytest under gitlab runner low performance

Tags: continuous-integration, pytest, gitlab-ci-runner

I am measuring the latency of a task on my unit test.
If I run the test via CLI, the test passed, instead, if I run the gitlab pipeline it fails because the task takes longer.

To be considered that runner doesn't work on docker container but on hardware directly.

Any suggestions?
Thanks